# How do I restore a committed file through GitHub?

Tags: html, git, github

Unfortunately, my computer crashed and I lost some lines of code that I typed.  I committed my changes through Git before it crashed, so my repository has all of the code I lost. (I'm not sure how I didn't save before committing, but definitely something to look out for in the future...) My question is: How do I go about restoring my old file from Github to my Desktop through Git?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Are you asking how to restore local work which might have been lost, or are you asking how to restore a version of a file from the remote branch?

Comment: **`git` is not GitHub**.

Comment: I second this @Dai! But I guess OP is a newbie so they might not be aware of this fact right now

Comment: Yes, VERY much a newbie so I apologize if the question is a very basic answer. Thank you everyone for the help! Figured it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood correctly, all you need to do is simply run 'git pull' on your terminal (if you are in the root directory of the project) and that's it. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the logs using `git log`.
Finding the commit you need and the using a `git reset`.

Here is some documentation if you need it: https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-reset